# Xpath "not" includes elements regardless

Tags: dom, xpath, xpathquery

My code returns the text only from the body of a webpage.  I am trying to remove text from `class="menu"` items from the body of this page:

```
<div id="pre-header-links-inner" class="header-links"><ul id="menu-top-bar" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="tel:000-000-0000">Main Line: +1 000-000-0000</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="tel:100000000000">Sales: tel:000-000-0000</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24"><a href="mailto:info@example.com">Email: info@example.com</a></li>
</ul></div>         
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #pre-header -->

        <div id="header">
        <div id="header-core">

            <div id="logo">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="253" height="50" src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Domain" itemprop="logo" /></a>           </div>

            <div id="header-links" class="main-navigation">
            <div id="header-links-inner" class="header-links">

                <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="https://www.example.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/services/"><span>Services</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/api/"><span>API</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>               

            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #header-links .main-navigation -->

            <div id="header-nav"><a class="btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #header -->

        <div id="header-responsive"><div id="header-responsive-inner" class="responsive-links nav-collapse collapse"><ul id="menu-main-navigation-1" class=""><li id="res-menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="https://example.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="res-menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li id="res-menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/services/"><span>Services</span></a></li>
<li id="res-menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/api/"><span>API</span></a></li>
<li id="res-menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul></div></div>
                <div id="header-sticky">
        <div id="header-sticky-core">

            <div id="logo-sticky">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="253" height="50" src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Logo" itemprop="logo" /></a>         </div>

            <div id="header-sticky-links" class="main-navigation">
            <div id="header-sticky-links-inner" class="header-links">

                <ul id="menu-main-navigation-2" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="https://www.example.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/services/"><span>Services</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/api/"><span>API</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.example.com/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Strange thing is - when I call the following line:

```
text = "".join(tree.xpath("//body//*[not(@class='menu')]//text()")).strip()
```

it returns the entire plain-text source code as-is (ie. even with the text from `class="text"` elements).

However, when I *remove* the `not` keyword:

```
text = "".join(tree.xpath("//body//*[(@class='menu')]//text()")).strip()
```

... it correctly identifies the text from the `class="text"` elements and isolates their text perfectly:

```
Main Line: +000-000-0000
Sales: +1 000-000-0000
Email: info@example.com
Home
About Us
Services
API
Contact Us
Home
About Us
Services
API
Contact Us
```

What am I doing it wrong?  I'd like it to return the text from everything EXCEPT elements where the `class='menu'`.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is look at the text nodes from the bottom up, using `ancestor`: `//body//text()[not(ancestor::ul[@class='menu'])]`.
That says: Get all text nodes that don’t have an ancestor that’s a `ul` element with `class="menu"`.

The problem with `//body//*[not(@class='menu')]//text()` is, the `//` in the expression causes it to be evaluated down to the deepest part of every subtree in the document—so it also selects, e.g., the `<a href="tel:100000000000">Sales: tel:000-000-0000</a>` element—because that element itself matches `//body//*[not(@class='menu')]`

Answer (score 0):

> it returns the entire plain-text source code

You need to be clear about the distinction between what the XPath expression SELECTS, and what the application handling the XPath result DISPLAYS.

XPath returns a set of nodes, and it is very common practice for the calling application to display each of those nodes by showing the entire subtree rooted at that node. But it's not XPath that's doing this; it's the calling application. Your selection criteria determine what nodes are selected by the XPath expression, but they don't affect which descendants of those selected nodes are displayed by the calling application.